# Should I use SolrJ to convert Lucene project into browser based search engine ?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

My current search engine involves two desktop applications based on Lucene (java). One is dedicated to indexing internal documents, the other one to searching.

Now I have been asked to offer the search engine as a web page. So my first thought was to use Solr, so I read the manual (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/overview-of-searching-in-solr.html) but then I realized that during the indexing phase we have special processing for PDFs. For example we detect whether the PDF originates from a scanned document, or we limit the number of pages that will be OCRed in a scanned PDFs since only the first pages are valuable for search. For now everything works via calls to Lucene API in classes with lots of if!

So my question is : should I use solrj to customize the indexing to our needs, should I keep the current indexing part and only use Solr(j) for searching, or should I overrides some Solr classes to meet our needs and avoid reinventing the wheel. For the latter (overriding Solr classes) how should I do ?

Thank you very much in advance for your advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is rather opinion based - I'll offer my opinion. All your suggested solutions would work, but the best one is to write the indexing code as a separate process, externally to Solr (i.e. re-use your existing code that pushes data to a Lucene index directly today).

Take the tool you have today, and instead of writing data to a Lucene index, use SolrJ and submit the document to Solr instead. That will abstract away the Lucene part of the code you're using today, but will still allow you to process PDFs in your custom way. Keeping the code outside of Solr will also make it *far* easier to update Solr in the future, or switch to a newer version of the PDF library you're using for parsing without having to coordinate and integrate it into Solr.

It'll also allow you to run the indexing code completely separate from Solr, and if you decide to drop Solr for another HTTP interfaced technology in the future (for example Elasticsearch which is also based on Lucene), you can rip out the small-ish part that pushes content to Solr and push it to Elasticsearch instead.

Running multiple indexing processes in parallel is also easier when as much as possible of the indexing code is outside of Solr, since Solr will only be concerned with the actual text - and don't have to spend time processing and parsing PDFs when it should just be responding to user queries (and your updates) instead.

Comment: I like your answer, I know now where I have to concentrate my efforts on. Thank you very much MatsLindh!